# Problem with htaccess causing images not to load

Tags: htaccess

In my htaccess file, i am using below lines

```
Options All -Indexes
Errordocument 403 http://article-stack.com/
ErrorDocument 401 http://article-stack.com/
ErrorDocument 403 http://article-stack.com/
ErrorDocument 404 http://article-stack.com/
ErrorDocument 500 http://article-stack.com/

<files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
Satisfy All
</files>
```

If I access some PHP inside my theme folder then it is working perfectly. But a php file in plugins folder with same permission is not accessible as i think so. Because my plugin on one [article](http://article-stack.com/other/amty-thumb-recent-is-now-amty-thumb-posts.amty) is not able to display images. When i copy the path of image and put it into browser directly, it is redirecting me to 404 page. If i run the same script from my theme folder then it is working perfectly.

It is also working fine from localhost even from plugins folder. There must be some problem with htaccess file only. But not able to guess what.

Comment: Your wording of the directory structure is a little confusing. Would you please update your question with a more specific directory structure and which HTTP error codes are returning for which files in that structure?

Comment: You shouldn't send users to your home page when a page isn't found or an error occurs. That's really darn confusing to users. Make custom pages for each error that explains what happened and what they should do. That's much better usability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well! the issue has been resolved. I was using capital "T" in url while accessing the path. Somehow I noticed it.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you only have the one .htaccess file, sounds like your plugin directory might be being controlled by another .htaccess file.